# Не могу сделать динамически изменяющиеся данные в шаблонах

Tags: html, python, django

Использую `Django 2.0` , пытаюсь сделать простенький блог с использованием бутстрап шаблона

`models.py` -

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from django.utils import timezone

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', {'posts': posts} )
```

`urls.py`

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='blog')
]
```

И часть `html` файла

```
<!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
       {% for post in posts %}
          <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="post.html">
              <h2 class="post-title">
                {{ post.title}}
              </h2>
              <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                {{post.text | linebreaksbr}}
              </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by
              <a href="#">{{post.author}}</a>
              on {{post.published_date}}</p>
          </div>
       {% endfor %}
          <!-- Pager -->
          <div class="clearfix">
            <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

При запуске в браузере мои посты почему-то не показываются (статику не подключал еще)

[image: пп]

Вот как должно быть в оригинале 
[image: оп]

Так же обращался в `python manage.py shell`, там все работает 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи!

Comment: Я бы для начала попробывал posts = Post.objects.all()

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич спасибо, помогло